# Select from @localvariable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of my server path, and I have a stored procedure where I need to call my server path base on the platform. I don't know why it's not working. Below is what I have so far.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [POLSAPSU].[SelectOrdersPOLDate] (@FROM DATETIME, @TO DATETIME)
AS

DECLARE @serverpath varchar(255)
DECLARE @query varchar(max)

BEGIN

SET @serverpath = (SELECT [path] from [param] where [platform] = 'POL')

SET @query = '

select 'POL' + '0'+ordh_sysrefno as ZINDEX,ordh_conttp AS POL_ORD_PKG_TYPE, ordh_pckgrefno AS POL_PKG_REFNO, '''' AS POL_PKG_PRODN, ''1101'' AS SALES_ORG, ''10'' AS DISTR_CHAN, ''11'' AS DIVISION, '''' AS POL_RTV_L_N, '''' AS CT_VALID_F, '''' AS CT_VALID_T, ordh_docno AS PURCH_NO_C 
from ' + @serverpath +'.ord_hdr A''
where cast(ordh_createdate as date) BETWEEN @FROM AND @TO 
    and Exists(select * from ' + @serverpath +'.ord_dtl B where B.ordd_sysrefno = ordh_sysrefno)
union
select ''POL''+pkgh_production+ pkgh_refno, pkgh_type, '''', pkgh_production, ''1101'', ''10'', ''11'', '',convert(varchar(8),pkgh_effst,112), convert(varchar(8),pkgh_effend,112), pkgh_docno 
from  ' + @serverpath + '.pckg_hdr where cast(pkgh_createdate as date) BETWEEN @FROM AND @TO'

EXEC (@query)

END
```

I'm getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '
> where cast(ordh_createdate as date) BETWEEN @FROM AND @TO
> and Exists(select * from POLTESTSERVER.POL.sysadm.ord_dtl B where '.

I am also considering this kind of approach

```
Select * from (select serverpath where platform = pol)
```

but I need to add the table name after the select statement in from clause and I don't have idea how. I am using SQL Server 2019.

Thank you.

Comment: When using dynamic SQL you have to build a string e.g. `from  @serverpath.pckg_hdr where` should be `from ' + serverpath + '.pckg_hdr where` or similar. You can't leave the variable in there, thats the exact propblem you are trying to solve.

Comment: You can easily debug dynamic SQL by using the print statement e.g. `PRINT(query)` and then you can easily see where you are going wrong.

Comment: `BETWEEN @FROM AND @TO'` And the same problem here. But really you should pass these are parameters to your dynamic SQL using sp_executesql

Comment: @DaleK I have edited my script I didn't notice the one you said earlier but im still getting the same error : Incorrect syntax near '
where cast(ordh_createdate as date) BETWEEN FROM AND TO 
 and Exists(select * from BMSTESTSERVER.BMS.sysadm.ord_dtl B where '.

Comment: @DaleK I tried Print query and the output is : Return Value 0

Comment: Not possible that print is returning that, I just tried it and got a query. Unless @serverpath is still null?

Comment: @DaleK I edit the script and make it ' ' POL ' '  + ' '0 ' ' but still getting the same error.

Comment: As I said print it then debug it - you have a bunch of mismatched single quotes, you haven't used the @To/@From variables correctly, all of which you will be able to solve very fast when you **print** the query you are attempting to run! I'm not going to list every mistake that needs correcting when you can do it yourself.

Comment: And as SMor said above use sp_executesql to pass @To/@From correctly. And if you use datetime windows you can avoid casting your column in the where clause which is bad for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found multiple issues here.

> 1. Date parameters inside the `sql` query string are not properly escaped.
> 2. Use `concat()` function instead of adding those constants and columns
> 3. Columns with empty values are not property escaped.

Try below updated script.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [POLSAPSU].[SelectOrdersPOLDate] (@FROM DATETIME, @TO DATETIME)
AS

DECLARE @serverpath varchar(255)
DECLARE @query varchar(max)

BEGIN

SET @serverpath = (SELECT [path] from [param] where [platform] = 'POL')

SET @query = '

select concat(''POL'',''0'', ordh_sysrefno) as ZINDEX
    ,ordh_conttp AS POL_ORD_PKG_TYPE, ordh_pckgrefno AS POL_PKG_REFNO
    , '''' AS POL_PKG_PRODN, ''1101'' AS SALES_ORG, ''10'' AS DISTR_CHAN, ''11'' AS DIVISION
    , '''' AS POL_RTV_L_N, '''' AS CT_VALID_F, '''' AS CT_VALID_T, ordh_docno AS PURCH_NO_C 
from ' + @serverpath +'.ord_hdr A 
where cast(ordh_createdate as date) BETWEEN '''+ cast(@FROM as varchar(30)) +''' AND '''+ cast(@TO as varchar(30))  +'''
    and Exists(select * from ' + @serverpath +'.ord_dtl B where B.ordd_sysrefno = ordh_sysrefno)
union
select concat(''POL'', pkgh_production, pkgh_refno), pkgh_type, '''', pkgh_production, ''1101'', ''10'', ''11'', '''', convert(varchar(8),pkgh_effst,112), convert(varchar(8),pkgh_effend,112), pkgh_docno 
from  ' + @serverpath +'.pckg_hdr where cast(pkgh_createdate as date) BETWEEN '''+ cast(@FROM as varchar(30)) +''' AND '''+ cast(@TO as varchar(30))  +''''


EXEC (@query)

END
```

Comment: Your script solve my problem. Thank you so much. But how about if I have multiple serverpath in single stored procedure?

Comment: @xtian you do exactly what the same thing with your multiple paths? You probably need to ask a new question.

Comment: `BETWEEN '''+ cast(@FROM as varchar(30)) +''' AND '''+ cast(@TO as varchar(30))  +'''` why not pass them through as parameters using `sp_executesql`

Comment: @Ed Bangga I have encountered another error where I try to select from a local variable. Can you help me again?